# is it possible to change name of endpoint in spring boot actuator

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

is it possible to change name of endpoint in spring boot actuator. For example i want to rename env to myenv. I am unable to find any property spring boot 2 , we had endpoints.env.id in spring boot 1.x.

Please assist here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , it's possible.
Add the following property and the path will be renamed.

```
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.env=myenv
```

Make sure to enable actuator env in properties. Add env in web exposure inlcude list

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=env
```

`myenv` will be available at `/actuator/myenv` unless you change `actuator` base path.

Tested with spring boot `2.3.4.RELEASE`.
For further information look at the official docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-monitoring).